# How to automatically convert text-based numbers to numbers in several files?

Tags: vba, excel

I have 1000 files in Excel format (Excel 2010) and each file contains 7 sheets with data.

This is an example for Excel sheet.

[image]

Is there a way to automatically convert the numbers that are stored as text to numbers, without affecting the actual text data? (maybe by VBA macros ? but I am a beginner in VBA code)

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an algorithm, but I don't have time to write the entire code. I would write it in a seperate workbook, for repeatability. You can then either hardcode the 7 file names, or you can make an input for file name (the latter is a bit more flexible, if you need to use it for more files later).

1. Open a file
2. Loop all sheets
3. Loop all cells
4. If IsNumeric(Cell.Value) > Change format

You should be able to Google your way to the separate parts. Once you have some actual code, you can ask for more help on StackOverflow.